# Calling instance() on shallow rendered functional component returns null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have following React functional component which accepts name as a prop

```
const Name = ({ name }) => <h1>{name}</h1>;

Name.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

And my test is as follows

```
describe("<Name />", () => {
    it("accepts name as a prop", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Name name="Monkey D Luffy"/>);
        expect(wrapper.instance().props.name).toBe("Monkey D Luffy");
    })
})
```

This returns following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null

**Update**

I am calling the Name component as follows

```
class Person extends React.Component {
  state = {name: "Name here"}
  render () {
     return  <div><Name name={this.state.name} /></div>
  }
}
```

I found out that calling `instance()` on a stateless component not gonna work with react 16.* I can not use `wrapper.prop()` in my case as it only returns the props of the root node

Why does it return null when calling instance function on the rendered component and how do I test props passed into a stateless component?

**Original Question**

Why does it return null when calling instance function on the rendered component

Comment: how's your component structured as you mentioned you can't use wrapper.prop()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`instance() === null` for functional component because functional components don't have instances.

Enzyme's own API should be used to access component props:

```
expect(wrapper.prop('children')).toBe("Monkey D Luffy");
```

As [the reference](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/props.html#props--object) explains,

> To return the props for the entire React component, use wrapper.instance().props. This is valid for stateful or stateless components in React 15.*. But, wrapper.instance() will return null for stateless React component in React 16.*, so wrapper.instance().props will cause an error in this case.

Comment: Thanks :) . I just found out that this is not working with react 16.*. It used to work with react 15.*

Comment: Yes, just added this part to the answer.

Comment: But I cant use `prop()`. prop will not return the name prop as it only returns values for props on the root node that the component renders, not the component itself.

Comment: I see what you mean. That's the obvious limitation of Enzyme because it renders root node. You can wrap it with a div if you need, `shallow(<div><Name ... /></div>` and `wrapper.find(Name).props()`. Why would you assert your own code you're writing in the test any way?

Comment: I want to test, if the passed name prop is rendered properly. I am trying to learn testing. so just playing around with enzyme and jest. Writing tests is new to me. So no idea what and what not to test :)

Comment: Then you're on the right track. You don't need to assert `name="Monkey D Luffy"` because that's the code you're written yourself one line above, you can be pretty much sure that it's ok. That's the reason why Enzyme doesn't even allow to check wrapper's own props, that's just not needed. You can assert how the component works by asserting that `wrapper.prop('children') === 'Monkey D Luffy'` (that's basically what it does) or `wrapper.html() === '<h1>Monkey D Luffy</h1>'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This comment resolved few more questions i had.